# Background-color issues for hyperlinked images

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm having a weird CSS problem on my blog, which you can see here: http://springecho.net/

For text links in my main content area, they have a background color and a different text color, which change on rollover.

With the images that are also hyperlinked, you see a black line at the bottom of them as a result of this CSS code. When you rollover the image, the black line disappears (duplicating the behaviour of the text links).

What can I change in the CSS to either fully hide the roll-over background color behind the images, or get it to not do it at all?

Many thanks! :)

Comment: Im seeing on the second video post when you hover over it, the text that is on the second line, the background covers the text, is this the issue your talking about? Sorry I can't seem to follow what the exact issue is.

Answer (score 2):

At first: The `background-color` just seems to be removed when hovering, cause it's then set to `#FFC909`.

The `vertical-align` is set to `baseline` for default, which means that there's still some space under the image. Simply set it to `top`:

```
a > img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly! thank you so much. wasn't aware of this "a > img" tag.

Comment: It simply means "all img elements, that are **direct** children of a tags".

Comment: PS: Please, don't for get to rate and accept. That's what StackOverflow relies on ;) ...